# TabHost.TabSpec layout that looks like the built-in layout

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost

I have some icons of varying height, and the default tabspec layout on my HTC Legend places the icon at the top.

I wanted to center it by defining my own layout for the tabspec, but after many experiments with style & background, I still can't make it look like the built-in layout.

So I need the built-in Padding & background for my tabspec layout, anyone knows what they're called?

Comment: Setting style to "@android:style/Widget.TabWidget" caused: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x1030034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much fiddling about - solved it by creating a fixed-height and variable width icon for the tab:

```
    private Drawable getTabIcon(byte chainID, Resources res) {
    BitmapDrawable chainIcon = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(ChainDisplay.getIconID(chainID));

    int tabIconHeight;
    switch(res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            tabIconHeight = 24;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            tabIconHeight = 32;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            tabIconHeight = 48;
            break;
        default:
            tabIconHeight = 48;
            break;
    }

    Bitmap tabIconBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(chainIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), tabIconHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    new Canvas(tabIconBitmap).drawBitmap(chainIcon.getBitmap(), 0, (tabIconHeight - chainIcon.getIntrinsicHeight())/2, null);
    return new BitmapDrawable(tabIconBitmap);
}
```

Did some experimenting with scaling and Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, but it was ugly, so image cropping was selected.